# How to add colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I don't really understand the documentation on colorbar I wanted explanation on a basic example. So below I am plotting exp(-x*a) for a={1, 2, 3, 4}. How do I add color bar with the values of a.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x,a):
    return np.exp(-x*a)
x = np.linspace(0, 5)

for a in range(1,5):
    plt.plot(func(x,a))
plt.show()
```

I'm confused with imshow, subplot, ax.

Comment: `imshow` does something completely different. `subplots` allows you to you guessed it create subplots. You can access the `ax` within the loop and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: you need a `colorbar` if you want to color-code value in the third dimension, `plot` shows a line plot  -  so the value is on the second dimension (y-axis), no need for a colorbar

Comment: It sounds like you really want a legend.  Maybe start with a tutorial or two: https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colour schemes are defined in the range 0 to 1, therefore you first need to normalise your values (0 to 5) to the range 0 to 1. Then you can pull the colour from the colormap. At the end you have to plot a color bar using the colour map and norm that you chose on the axis you used for plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors


def func(x, a):
    return np.exp(-x * a)


x = np.linspace(0, 5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# define color map
cmap = cm.get_cmap("Spectral")

# need to normalize because color maps are defined in [0, 1]
norm = colors.Normalize(0, 5)

for a in range(1, 5):
    ax.plot(x, func(x, a), 
        color=cmap(norm(a)))  # get color from color map 

# plot colorbar
fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

The plot looks like this:[image]